# Deploying an updated ssis package while its production version is still executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis-2012

What happens to a SSIS package that is running when doing a deployment on top of it?

SQL Server 2012, SSIS Catalog.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it with SQL2016 RC2.  The running package keeps running and the new deploy works successfully.  Once the running package finished I looked at the properties and the current version was updated to the new version.

So, while I could not find any documentation on this, I believe that SQL SSISDB updates to the new version without doing anything to currently running processes / packages.

Answer (score 0):

When a SSIS package is executed, the package is loaded into memory.  If there are package configurations, they are applied next.  Then the package starts executing.
So, once the package is executing, changing the package by deploying a new version of it does not affect the one that is executing.